# Compute number of matrices with appropriate sums

Tags: code-golf, math, combinatorics

When multiplying monomials in the Milnor basis for the Steenrod algebra, part of the algorithm involves enumerating certain "allowable matrices".

Given two lists of nonnegative integers *r<sub>1</sub>*, ... ,*r<sub>m</sub>* and  *s<sub>1</sub>*, ... ,*s<sub>n</sub>*, a matrix of nonnegative integers X

[image: a matrix]

is allowable if

1. The sum of the jth column is less than or equal to *s<sub>j</sub>*:

   [image: column sums constraint]
2. The sum of the ith row weighted by powers of 2 is less than or equal to *r<sub>i</sub>*:

   [image: row sums constraint]

### Task

Write a program which takes a pair of lists *r<sub>1</sub>*, ... ,*r<sub>m</sub>* and *s<sub>1</sub>*, *s<sub>1</sub>*, ... ,*s<sub>n</sub>* and computes the number of allowable matrices for these lists. Your program may optionally take m and n as additional arguments if need be.

- These numbers may be input in any format one likes, for instance grouped into lists or encoded in unary, or anything else.
- Output should be a positive integer
- Standard loopholes apply.

### Scoring

This is code golf: Shortest solution in bytes wins.

### Examples:

For `[2]` and `[1]`, there are two allowable matrices:

[image: example 1]

For `[4]` and `[1,1]` there are three allowable matrices:

[image: example 2]

For `[2,4]` and `[1,1]` there are five allowable matrices:

[image: example 3]

### Test cases:

```
   Input: [1], [2]
   Output: 1

   Input: [2], [1]
   Output: 2

   Input: [4], [1,1]
   Output: 3

   Input: [2,4], [1,1]   
   Output: 5      

   Input: [3,5,7], [1,2]
   Output: 14

   Input: [7, 10], [1, 1, 1]
   Output: 15       

   Input: [3, 6, 16, 33], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
   Output: 38      

   Input: [7, 8], [3, 3, 1]
   Output: 44

   Input: [2, 6, 15, 18], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
   Output: 90       

   Input: [2, 6, 7, 16], [1, 3, 2]
   Output: 128

   Input: [2, 7, 16], [3, 3, 1, 1]
   Output: 175
```

Comment: IMO the definition would be easier to understand if you lose the first row and column of the matrices, index from 1, and use <= instead of ==.

Comment: Okay, will do. I just copied the definition out of a math textbook and it had an actual use for those entries.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES7), 163 bytes

```js
f=([R,...x],s)=>1/R?[...Array(R**s.length)].reduce((k,_,n)=>(a=s.map((_,i)=>n/R**i%R|0)).some(c=>(p+=c<<++j)>R,p=j=0)?k:k+f(x,s.map((v,i)=>v-a[i])),0):!/-/.test(s)
```

#### Test cases

**NB**: I've removed the two most time-consuming test cases from this snippet, but they should pass as well.

```js
f=([R,...x],s)=>1/R?[...Array(R**s.length)].reduce((k,_,n)=>(a=s.map((_,i)=>n/R**i%R|0)).some(c=>(p+=c<<++j)>R,p=j=0)?k:k+f(x,s.map((v,i)=>v-a[i])),0):!/-/.test(s)

console.log(f([1],[2]))            // 1
console.log(f([2],[1]))            // 2
console.log(f([4],[1,1]))          // 3
console.log(f([2,4],[1,1]   ))     // 5      
console.log(f([3,5,7],[1,2]))      // 14
console.log(f([7,10],[1,1,1]))     // 15       
console.log(f([7,8],[3,3,1]))      // 44
console.log(f([2,6,7,16],[1,3,2])) // 128
console.log(f([2,7,16],[3,3,1,1])) // 175
```

#### Commented

```js
f = (                               // f = recursive function taking:
  [R,                               //   - the input array r[] splitted into:
      ...x],                        //     R = next element / x = remaining elements
  s                                 //   - the input array s[]
) =>                                //
  1 / R ?                           // if R is defined:
    [...Array(R**s.length)]         //   for each n in [0, ..., R**s.length - 1],
    .reduce((k, _, n) =>            //   using k as an accumulator:
      (a =                          //     build the next combination a[] of
        s.map((_, i) =>             //     N elements in [0, ..., R - 1]
          n / R**i % R | 0          //     where N is the length of s[]
        )                           //
      ).some(c =>                   //     for each element c in a[]:
        (p += c << ++j)             //       increment j; add c * (2**j) to p
        > R,                        //       exit with a truthy value if p > R
        p = j = 0                   //       start with p = j = 0
      ) ?                           //     end of some(); if truthy:
        k                           //       just return k unchanged
      :                             //     else:
        k +                         //       add to k the result of
        f(                          //       a recursive call to f() with:
          x,                        //         the remaining elements of r[]
          s.map((v, i) => v - a[i]) //         s[] updated by subtracting the values of a[]
        ),                          //       end of recursive call
      0                             //     initial value of the accumulator k
    )                               //   end of reduce()
  :                                 // else:
    !/-/.test(s)                    //   return true if there's no negative value in s[]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 26 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
UḄ€Ḥ>⁴
0rŒpṗ⁴L¤µS>³;ÇẸµÐḟL
```

A full program taking **S**, **R** which prints the count

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUsAtP9qZWxsef//VeG4hOKCrOG4pD7igbQKMHLFknDhuZfigbRMwqTCtVM@wrM7w4fhurjCtcOQ4bifTP///1szLCAzLCAxXf9bNywgOF0)**

#### How?

```
UḄ€Ḥ>⁴ - Link 1, row-wise comparisons: list of lists, M
U      - upend (reverse each)
 Ḅ€    - convert €ach from binary (note bit-domain is unrestricted, e.g. [3,4,5] -> 12+8+5)
   Ḥ   - double (vectorises) (equivalent to the required pre-bit-shift by one)
     ⁴ - program's 2nd input, R
    >  - greater than? (vectorises)

0rŒpṗ⁴L¤µS>³;ÇẸµÐḟL - Main link: list S, list R
0r                  - inclusive range from 0 to s for s in S
  Œp                - Cartesian product of those lists
       ¤            - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
     ⁴              -   program's 2nd input, R
      L             -   length
    ṗ               - Cartesian power = all M with len(R) rows & column values in [0,s]
        µ      µÐḟ  - filter discard if:
         S          -   sum (vectorises) = column sums
           ³        -   program's 1st input, S
          >         -   greater than? (vectorises) = column sum > s for s in S
             Ç      -   call the last link (1) as a monad = sum(2^j × row) > r for r in R
            ;       -   concatenate
              Ẹ     -   any truthy?
                  L - length
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 101 bytes

Let Mathematica solve it as a system of inequalities over the integers.  I set up a symbolic array in `f` and thread over three sets of inequalities. `Join@@` just flattens the list for `Solve`.

```
Length@Solve[Join@@Thread/@{Tr/@(t=f~Array~{q=(l=Length)@#2,l@#})<=#2,2^Range@q.t<=#,t>=0},Integers]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxBawIxEIX/SkAoCkPdJLrrwcj02NJDqd5EIbQxu7BGTEOhhPjXt6PRVUhm3jfvzex1qM1eh@ZLd1Z178bZUOPy0P6a9duhcYir2hv9Pca48mMcBrU7vXiv/07xqIatygsjHAhocZBGc0VKbD@1swaPz4EYwkIVCV5dMNb4n81T9@EbF9YWEWOMPEEUiQpVIDqryVlB1gIeScIUqgvnnQp4ke0@UAIvQUqCAjjcnQpm1CTI/jArgfEpfTIY3WD395CoCMtrQAITN6ufy8s8b6VN9w8)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica 139 bytes

```
Tr@Boole[k=Length[a=#]+1;AllTrue[a-Rest[##+0],#>=0&]&@@@Tuples[BinCounts[#,{2r~Prepend~0}]&/@IntegerPartitions[#,All,r=2^Range@k/2]&/@#2]]&
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##TU5Na4QwEL33VwwIe@kUNelqoVjs9lToQcSbtRDawZV14xJjL@L@dTt@dHdDMnlv3nuTHJXd01HZ6luNZfQ5ZibeNU1N@QEi@CBd2n2uGDoF3IP/DHcA8FrXmemI@w@QUmtzx2HRKxAceInAg00BG4jjeHZD1p1qavNdpd@aTts2dxB6AeacGDqR/jl7w@R3V/u03rWlkkyijK1s1eg5w88iGP6L@EqVLik@uGINOqJgNCam0jYv@eWUfsm05MZ93/sD9mLgwhWZTehxQrhggbdM4hbDmS@ZEH1vkS@GAP0ApWTioY9XJcQnviTKy2AIEPwtHxaAZ8B13zhCpsFqkAjiX7r05dxfUkMx/gE)

Explanation: Partitions each of the *r<sub>i</sub>* into powers of 2 and then makes all tuples with one decomposition into powers of two for each integer, subtract the column totals from the list of the *s<sub>i</sub>*. Count the number of tuples that make all remaining entries are positive.

Comment: typically it's discouraged to answer your own challenge until others have submitted in that language already.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I can delete it if you think that's a good idea. This isn't super carefully golfed, so it's very likely others can do better.

Comment: While it's not a bad thing to be able to prove it's solvable, I don't recommend spoiling the solution so quickly. Maybe wait for a week first or something.

Comment: So should I delete it or leave it now that I posted it?

Comment: I would leave it. *Pace* Erik I don't think it spoils anything: the existence of a solution is obvious from the fact that the matrices respecting the column sum constraint are finite and easily generated.

Comment: Leave it. I just put in another M answer which takes a totally different approach.